# How to get 2 radio buttons aligned correctly with Swing GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I can't get GridBagLayout to work as I'd like. I'm trying to get 2 radio buttons to align next to each other. The best I can get is inches apart. I've played with weights to no avail. Currently I have my labels spanned over 2 cells. I have my radio buttons using 1 cell each with a 2 cell label. The last row is a 2 cell label and 2 cell date control. Maybe GridBagLayout is not the correct manager.

```
public class GridBagLayoutTest extends JFrame {
    
    private final JPanel addScorePanel;
    private final JTextField txtScore;
    private final JRadioButton rb9;
    private final JRadioButton rb18;
    private final JDateChooser dateChooserDate;
    
    public GridBagLayoutTest() {

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        
        addScorePanel = new JPanel();
        addScorePanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        
        txtScore = new JTextField(3);
        
        rb9 = new JRadioButton("9");
        rb9.setActionCommand("9");
        
        rb18 = new JRadioButton("18");
        rb18.setActionCommand("18");
        rb18.setSelected(true);
        
        ButtonGroup bgHoles = new ButtonGroup();
        bgHoles.add(rb9);
        bgHoles.add(rb18);
        
        dateChooserDate = new JDateChooser();
        
        layoutControls();
        
        add(addScorePanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(600, 430);                                                          // Juggle for best look
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 375));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        }
    

    private void layoutControls() {

        Border titleBorder = BorderFactory.
                createTitledBorder("Handicap Add Score");
        
        int space = 15;
        Border spaceBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(space, space, 
                space, space);
        
        addScorePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(spaceBorder, 
                titleBorder));
        
//        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));

        GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;                                          // Controls preferred size, 
        
        ////////// Score row //////////
        gc.gridy = 0;
        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.weightx = 1.0;
        gc.weighty = 1.0;
        gc.gridwidth = 2;                                                           // Label 2 cells
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_END;
        gc.insets = new Insets(15, 0, 0, 15);
        addScorePanel.add(new JLabel("Score: "), gc);
        
        gc.gridy = 0;
        gc.gridx = 2;                                                               // Skip over 2nd label cell
        gc.gridwidth = 1;
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        gc.insets = new Insets(15, 0, 0, 15);
        addScorePanel.add(txtScore, gc);

        ////////// Holes row //////////
        gc.gridy++;
        gc.gridx = 0;
//        gc.weightx = 0.1;
//        gc.weighty = 1.0;
        gc.gridwidth = 2;                                                           // Label 2 cells
        gc.insets = new Insets(15, 0, 0, 15);
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_END;
        addScorePanel.add(new JLabel("Holes Played:"), gc);
        
        gc.gridx = 2;                                                               // Skip over 2nd label cell
//        gc.weightx = 0.1;
        gc.gridwidth = 1;
        gc.insets = new Insets(15, 0, 0, 0);
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        addScorePanel.add(rb9, gc);
         
        gc.gridx++;                                                                 // Next cell
//        gc.weightx = 1.0;
        gc.gridwidth = 1;
        gc.insets = new Insets(15, 0, 0, 0);
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        addScorePanel.add(rb18, gc);
        
        ////////// Date row //////////
        gc.gridy++;
        gc.gridx = 0;
//        gc.weightx = 1.0;
//        gc.weighty = 1.0;
        gc.gridwidth = 2;                                                           // Label 2 cells
        gc.insets = new Insets(15, 0, 0, 15);
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_END;
        addScorePanel.add(new JLabel("Date: "), gc);
        
        gc.gridx = 2;                                                               // Skip over 2nd label cell
        gc.gridwidth = 2;                                                           // Date 2 cells
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        addScorePanel.add(dateChooserDate, gc);
    }
```

This is what I am trying to do:

[image: Sample output]

EDIT based on @camickr:

```
        ////////// Score row //////////
        gc.gridy = 0;
        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.weightx = 1.0;
        gc.weighty = 1.0;
        gc.gridwidth = 1;                                   // <-----               // Label 2 cells
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_END;
        gc.insets = new Insets(15, 0, 0, 15);
        addScorePanel.add(new JLabel("Score: "), gc);
        
        gc.gridy = 0;
        gc.gridx = 1;                                       // <-----                // Skip over 2nd label cell
        gc.gridwidth = 2;                                   // <----- 
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        gc.insets = new Insets(15, 0, 0, 15);
        addScorePanel.add(txtScore, gc);

        ////////// Holes row //////////
        gc.gridy++;
        gc.gridx = 0;
//        gc.weightx = 0.1;
//        gc.weighty = 1.0;
        gc.gridwidth = 1;                                    // <-----              // Label 2 cells
        gc.insets = new Insets(15, 0, 0, 15);
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_END;
        addScorePanel.add(new JLabel("Holes Played:"), gc);
        
        gc.gridx = 1;                                       // <-----               // Skip over 2nd label cell
//        gc.weightx = 0.1;
        gc.gridwidth = 1;
        gc.insets = new Insets(15, 0, 0, 0);
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        addScorePanel.add(rb9, gc);
         
        gc.gridx = 2;                                       // <-----               // Next cell
//        gc.weightx = 1.0;
        gc.gridwidth = 1;
        gc.insets = new Insets(15, 0, 0, 0);
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        addScorePanel.add(rb18, gc);
        
        ////////// Date row //////////
        gc.gridy++;
        gc.gridx = 0;
//        gc.weightx = 1.0;
//        gc.weighty = 1.0;
        gc.gridwidth = 1;                                 // <-----                 // Label 2 cells
        gc.insets = new Insets(15, 0, 0, 15);
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_END;
        addScorePanel.add(new JLabel("Date: "), gc);
        
        gc.gridx = 1;                                                               // Skip over 2nd label cell
        gc.gridwidth = 2;                                                           // Date 2 cells
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        addScorePanel.add(dateChooserDate, gc);
```

Looks pretty much the same. I think I marked my changes correctly.

Comment: Add the radio buttons to a panel using a `FlowLayout`. Then add the panel to the GridBagLayout. Nesting panels with different layout managers can help simplify layouts. *I have my labels spanned over 2 cells.* - no you don't. The width of a cell is determined by the width of the largest component added to that column. It only works if you have another row with multiple components. A solution using a single panel  would be to have the labels in column 1 the radio buttons in columns 2 and 3. Then have your text fields in column 2 with a gridwidth of 2.

Comment: @camickr I think I made the changes you suggested, in my edited post. They make sense to me, but got the same result. FlowLayout seems like the better solution, but I'm trying to get a better understanding of how GridBagLayout works. Please let me know if I screwed up somewhere.

Comment: Yes, using a panel for the radio buttons is the better solution (which is why I suggested it first). If you really want to group components they should be on the same panel and treated as a single column. *I'm trying to get a better understanding of how GridBagLayout works* -  you are artificially setting the size of the frame by using the setSize() and setMinimumSize() methods. Then because you are also using the "weightx" constraint, the columns are being resized wider to take up the extra space. So both radio buttons get extra space.

Comment: Instead you should be using the pack() method to properly size the frame. After the frame is packed then maybe set the minimum size to the actual size of the frame. So remove all the weightx/y and insets constraints and the hardcoded frame sizes. Retest to see the fully packed layout. Then resize the frame wider to see what happens. Then add back in the and insets constraints one at a time to get better spacing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) section.

I used multiple Swing layouts to get the layout you wanted.

[image]

All Swing applications must start with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that the Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

I used a `JFrame`.  The only reason you would extend a Swing component, or any Java class, is if you want to override one or more of the class methods.

I put the `JRadioButtons` inside a `JPanel` with a `FlowLayout`.

I simplified the main `JPanel` using a `GridBagLayout`.  It's unusual to right justify the `JLabels`, but I showed you how to do so.

You probably want to add a `JButton` to trigger an `ActionListener` to read the input fields.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class GridBagLayoutTest implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new GridBagLayoutTest());
    }

    private JTextField txtScore;
    private JRadioButton rb9;
    private JRadioButton rb18;
    private JTextField dateChooserDate;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        Border titleBorder = BorderFactory
                .createTitledBorder("Handicap Add Score");
        int space = 15;
        Border spaceBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(space, space,
                space, space);
        panel.setBorder(
                BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(spaceBorder, titleBorder));

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(15, 0, 0, 15);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(createJLabel("Score:"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx++;
        txtScore = new JTextField(10);
        panel.add(txtScore, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        panel.add(createJLabel("Holes Played:"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx++;
        panel.add(createRadioPanel(), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        panel.add(createJLabel("Date:"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx++;
        dateChooserDate = new JTextField(10);
        panel.add(dateChooserDate, gbc);

        return panel;
    }

    private JLabel createJLabel(String text) {
        JLabel label = new JLabel(text);
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.TRAILING);

        return label;
    }

    private JPanel createRadioPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        rb9 = new JRadioButton("9");
        rb9.setActionCommand("9");
        panel.add(rb9);

        rb18 = new JRadioButton("18");
        rb18.setActionCommand("18");
        panel.add(rb18);

        ButtonGroup bgHoles = new ButtonGroup();
        bgHoles.add(rb9);
        bgHoles.add(rb18);

        return panel;
    }

}
```

Comment: I know about using SwingUtilities invokeLater method and ActionListeners, I just threw this together for what I am trying to do with GBL visually. I think you and @camickr hit it with FlowLayout, but I am trying to understand if I can do this all with GBL? Curious, are labels generally left justified comment about JFrame is noted. I don't normally extend.

Comment: @todivefor: Why?  If you want to struggle with GridBagLayout, go ahead.  Me, I'd just as soon complete the GUI and move on to something else.  Yes, in a form, labels are usually left justified.

Comment: Struggle with layout managers. Just trying to learn when to use GBL and when not too.

Comment: @todivefor: It's simple.  When you need a form, one or more columns of `JLabels` and `JTextFields`, you use a `GridBagLayout`.  Otherwise, you break your GUI down into the simplest sets of Swing components you can and combine `BorderLayout`, `FlowLayout`, and `GridLayout`, with an occasional `BoxLayout`.  You're welcome.

Comment: LeBlanc, from your example, it's obvious this comes easy for you. I'm a retired assembly language dinosaur, java hobiest. Not so easy. Thank you.